# Setting up an environment for benchmarking XDP load balancer

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I want to do benchmarking against XDP LBs which are deployed within virtual machines. Besides these LBs, there exist a ingress switch (also a VM) which helps splitting the traffic to each LB.

Is [ECMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing) the most-recommended way to be used within the ingress switch here? If it isn't, is there any better (or appropriate) way for my scerario?

I was earlier using ECMP but it's somehow not forwarding traffic properly (tcpdump at another machine didn't sniff any packets came out from it). I want to know that whether this is a feasible way before doing any further check against my ECMP configuration.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to benchmark? Putting the switch in a VM isn't very realistic and will strongly degrade the throughput and latency.

Comment: @FengMa are you trying to physcial pass through the NIC using SRIOV into VM? then run XDP logic inside VM vcpu? Assuming you do all these with high performance and dedicated memory and CPU you can run ingress switch logic in VM. Can you help me understand what are `TX ports`? are these virtio ports? and is your question `should I implement round-robin, ecmp, consistent-hashing as Load balancer logic with XDP`? Please clarify?